# Determine the set of the limit points of the sequence {$a_n$} ,where $a_n$ = $\frac{2n^2}{7}$ - $[\frac{2n^2} {7}]$

Tags: real-analysis

Determine the  set of the limit points  of the  sequence      {$a_n$}  ,where  $a_n$ = $\frac{2n^2}{7}$ - $[\frac{2n^2} {7}]$

My answer :i thinks  $0$   will be the limit points  because $a_n$ = $\frac{2n^2}{7}$ - $[\frac{2n^2} {7}] \ge 0$

is it true ?

Any Hints /solution  will be appreciated

thanks  i advance....

Comment: If by $\;[ ]\;$ you mean the floor function then the question is weird, as $\;[2n^2]=2n^2\,,\,\,[7]=7\;$ ....What did you **really** mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio..see i have  edited...that  was my Typo mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation: $q-[q]=\{q\}$.

**Obs 1:** if $n=7k+r$, with $r\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, then $\left\{\frac{n}{7}\right\}=r/7$.

**Obs 2:** if $n=7k+r$, with $r\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, then $2n^2\equiv 0,2,1,4,4,1,2\mod 7$, respectively.

With this, we can note that $a_n=\left\{\frac{2n^2}{7}\right\}$ can be only $0,1/7,2/7, 4/7$  and this values can be reached endless times interspersed.

Then, their are the limit points

Edited for more clarification: This subsequences are constant

- $a_{7k}=0$ for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$.
- $a_{7k+2}=1/7$ for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$.
- $a_{7k+1}=2/7$ for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$.
- $a_{7k+3}=4/7$ for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: thanks u Martin